# No step marker observed on tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on keras model with an LSTM. To optimize performance I'd like to use the performance profiler from TensorBoard.

However it shows this error message at the top:

> No step marker observed and hence the step time is unknown. This may happen if (1) training steps are not instrumented (e.g., if you are not using Keras) or (2) the profiling duration is shorter than the step time. For (1), you need to add step instrumentation; for (2), you may try to profile longer.

This is my keras model:

```
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=tuple(config.input_dims)),
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])

        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], optimizer="adam")
        model.summary()
        model.fit(x=train, validation_data=validation, epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks)
```

If I replace the LSTM with a flatten layer the profiler shows correct data.
The model can be trained and used. Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message "No step marker observed and hence the step time is unknown...", and fixed it by changing TensorFlow version: `pip install tensorflow==2.9`, then I re-ran the code and the profiling information appeared in TensorBoard correctly.

(the complete lack of useful error messages is rather infuriating...)

Comment: This seems like the only solution in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Above that warning, an error is shown: "Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)". As I checked when executing the model and observed that TensorFlow could not find CUPTI. So linked it as it is mentioned [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Could_not_load_dynamic_library_libcuptiso110_dlerror_libcuptiso110_cannot_open_shared_object_file).

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP's issue and the answer are unrelated as the issue is solved by swapping out a layer for another. I'm having a similar issue as well and OP's workaround is a great clue.